# Re-Apply currency formatting to a UITextField on a change event

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, currency, nsnumberformatter

I'm working with a UITextField that holds a localized currency value.  I've seen lots of posts on how to work with this, but my question is: how do I re-apply currency formatting to the UITextField after every key press?

I know that I can set up and use a currency formatter with:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
...
[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:...];
```

but I don't know how to hook it up.

For instance, if the value in the field reads "$12,345" and the user taps the "6" key, then the value should change to "$123,456".

Which callback is the "correct" one to do this in (should I use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` or a custom target-action) and how do I use the NSNumberFormatter to parse and re-apply formatting to the UITextField's text property?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've been working on this issue and I think I figured out a nice, clean solution. I'll show you how to appropriately update the textfield on user input, but you'll have to figure out the localization yourself, that part should be easy enough anyway.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // setup text field ...

#define PADDING 10.0f

    const CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    CGFloat width       = bounds.size.width - (PADDING * 2);
    CGFloat height      = 30.0f;
    CGRect frame        = CGRectMake(PADDING, PADDING, width, height);

    self.textField                      = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _textField.backgroundColor          = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    _textField.autocapitalizationType   = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    _textField.autocorrectionType       = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    _textField.text                     = @"0";
    _textField.delegate                 = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_textField];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    // force update for text field, so the initial '0' will be formatted as currency ...

    [self textField:_textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) replacementString:@"0"];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.textField = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

This is the code in the *UITextFieldDelegate* method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *text             = _textField.text;
    NSString *decimalSeperator = @".";
    NSCharacterSet *charSet    = nil;
    NSString *numberChars      = @"0123456789";


    // the number formatter will only be instantiated once ...

    static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter;
    if (!numberFormatter)
    {
        numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        numberFormatter.numberStyle           = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10;
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
        numberFormatter.decimalSeparator      = decimalSeperator;
        numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = NO;
    }


    // create a character set of valid chars (numbers and optionally a decimal sign) ...

    NSRange decimalRange = [text rangeOfString:decimalSeperator];
    BOOL isDecimalNumber = (decimalRange.location != NSNotFound);
    if (isDecimalNumber)
    {
        charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:numberChars];        
    }
    else
    {
        numberChars = [numberChars stringByAppendingString:decimalSeperator];
        charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:numberChars];
    }


    // remove amy characters from the string that are not a number or decimal sign ...

    NSCharacterSet *invertedCharSet = [charSet invertedSet];
    NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:invertedCharSet];
    text = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:trimmedString];


    // whenever a decimalSeperator is entered, we'll just update the textField.
    // whenever other chars are entered, we'll calculate the new number and update the textField accordingly.

    if ([string isEqualToString:decimalSeperator] == YES) 
    {
        textField.text = text;
    }
    else 
    {
        NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:text];
        if (number == nil) 
        {
            number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];   
        }
        textField.text = isDecimalNumber ? text : [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
    }

    return NO; // we return NO because we have manually edited the textField contents.
}
```

**Edit 1:** fixed memory leak.

**Edit 2:** updated for Umka - handling of `0` after decimal separator. Code is updated for ARC as well.

Comment: Very good! I will use this code...I did have to make one change to allow a "0" value after the decimal. Otherwise the decimal gets wiped out when you try and enter a value like "2.04"

Comment: No changes from Clinemi committed seems. At least 0 is still wiped out.

Comment: I made a fix for the *`0` after decimal separator* issue. Code is cleaned-up and updated for ARC as well now. This should be what you need.

Comment: This is a perfect code for cases, when the currency symbol is in front of the number, but it doesn't work, in cases when the currency symbol is at the end of number. For example, in Russia it must be formatted like this: "500 руб.".

Answer (score 4):

This was good basis but still did not satisfy my app needs. Here is what I cooked to help it. I understand that code is actually cumbersome and it is here rather to give a clue and may be to get more elegant solution.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)aTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
        if (aTextField == myAmountTextField) {
                NSString *text = aTextField.text;
                NSString *decimalSeperator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
                NSString *groupSeperator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];

                NSCharacterSet *characterSet = nil;
                NSString *numberChars = @"0123456789";
                if ([text rangeOfString:decimalSeperator].location != NSNotFound)
                        characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:numberChars];
                else
                        characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[numberChars stringByAppendingString:decimalSeperator]];

                NSCharacterSet *invertedCharSet = [characterSet invertedSet];   
                NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:invertedCharSet];
                text = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:trimmedString];

                if ([string isEqualToString:decimalSeperator] == YES ||
                    [text rangeOfString:decimalSeperator].location == text.length - 1) {
                        [aTextField setText:text];
                } else {
                        /* Remove group separator taken from locale */
                        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:groupSeperator withString:@""];


                        /* Due to some reason, even if group separator is ".", number
                        formatter puts spaces instead. Lets handle this. This all should
                        be done before converting to NSNUmber as otherwise we will have
                        nil. */
                        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                        NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:text];
                        if (number == nil) {
                                [textField setText:@""];
                        } else {
                                /* Here is what I call "evil miracles" is going on :)
                                Totally not elegant but I did not find another way. This
                                is all needed to support inputs like "0.01" and "1.00" */
                                NSString *tail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@00", decimalSeperator];
                                if ([text rangeOfString:tail].location != NSNotFound) {
                                        [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#,###,##0.00"];
                                } else {
                                        tail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0", decimalSeperator];
                                        if ([text rangeOfString:tail].location != NSNotFound) {
                                                [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#,###,##0.0#"];
                                        } else {
                                                [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#,###,##0.##"];
                                        }
                                }
                                text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
                                [textField setText:text];
                        }
                }

                return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Number formatter is initialized in a way like this:

```
numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
numberFormatter.roundingMode = kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor;
```

It is locale aware, so should work fine in different locale setups. It also supports the following inputs (examples):

0.00
0.01

1,333,333.03

Please somebody improve this. Topic is kind of interesting, no elegant solution exists so far (iOS has not setFormat() thing).

Answer (score 4):

Here's my version of this.

Setup a formatter some place:

```
    // Custom initialization
    formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setLenient:YES];
    [formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
```

Then use it to parse and format the UITextField:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *replaced = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSDecimalNumber *amount = (NSDecimalNumber*) [formatter numberFromString:replaced];
    if (amount == nil) {
        // Something screwed up the parsing. Probably an alpha character.
        return NO;
    }
    // If the field is empty (the inital case) the number should be shifted to
    // start in the right most decimal place.
    short powerOf10 = 0;
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        powerOf10 = -formatter.maximumFractionDigits;
    }
    // If the edit point is to the right of the decimal point we need to do
    // some shifting.
    else if (range.location + formatter.maximumFractionDigits >= textField.text.length) {
        // If there's a range of text selected, it'll delete part of the number
        // so shift it back to the right.
        if (range.length) {
            powerOf10 = -range.length;
        }
        // Otherwise they're adding this many characters so shift left.
        else {
            powerOf10 = [string length];
        }
    }
    amount = [amount decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:powerOf10];

    // Replace the value and then cancel this change.
    textField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:amount];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: In case that currency symbol is not the same as current locale (and managed separately), I would also kill it from the string itself. Juts replace the line before return with this: aTextField.text = [amount stringValue];

Comment: While it works fine in simulator, I found one issue on iphone5. This line NSDecimalNumber *amount = (NSDecimalNumber *)[numberFormatter numberFromString:@"0.011"]; yields 11 :) I tried to setup number formatter in various ways (set locale, decimal separator, number of fractional digits) but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

For simple ATM style currency entry, I use the following code, which works quite well, **if** you use the `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` option, which allows only digits and backspaces.

First set up an `NSNumberFormatter` like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter* currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:9]; // max number of digits including ones after the decimal here
```

Then, use the following shouldChangeCharactersInRange code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString* newText = [[[[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currencyFormatter.currencySymbol withString:[NSString string]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator withString:[NSString string]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator withString:[NSString string]];
    NSInteger newValue = [newText integerValue];

    if ([newText length] == 0 || newValue == 0)
        textField.text = nil;
    else if ([newText length] > currencyFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits)
        textField.text = textField.text;
    else
        textField.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:newValue / 100.0]];

    return NO;
}
```

Most of the work is done in setting the `newText` value; the proposed change is used but all non-digit characters put in by `NSNumberFormatter` are taken out.

Then the first if test checks to see if the text is empty or all zeros (put there by the user or the formatter). If not, the next test makes sure that no more input except backspaces will be accepted if the number is already at the maximum number of digits.

The final else re-displays the number using the formatter so the user always sees something like `$1,234.50`. Note that I use a `$0.00` for the placeholder text with this code, so setting the text to nil shows the placeholder text.

Comment: I stumbled across this while working to add regional currency to my app, based on the chosen region in iOS settings. This code worked fine sometimes, but resulted in all results being 0 for some regions. Please see my answer based on this code to view the way I fixed it. I also broke up the newText assignment to make it easier for us less experienced coders to digest whats going on there.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an open source `UITextField` subclass to handle this, available here:

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSCurrencyTextField

It's very easy to use - just drop it in place of any UITextField.  You can still provide a UITextFieldDelegate if you like, but this is not required.

Comment: what if the currency symbol is at the end of the text?

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds a little on Michael Klosson's code to fix some regional currency bugs, some locations caused his code to always spit out a 0 value in the final conversion back to textField string. I've also broke down the newText assignment to make it easier for some of us newer coders to digest, the nesting is tiresome for me sometimes. I logged out all NSLocale location options and their maximumFractionDigits value when an NSNUmberFormatter is set to them. I've found there were only 3 possibilities. Most use 2, some others use none, and a few use 3. This textfield delegate method handles all 3 possibilities, to ensure proper format based on region.

Here is my textField delegate method, mainly just a rewrite of Michael's code, but with the newText assignment expanded out, regional decimal support added, and using NSDecimalNumbers as thats what I'm storing in my core data model anyway.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
        // get the format symbols
        NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = self.currencyFormatter;
        NSString *currencySymbol = currencyFormatter.currencySymbol;
        NSString *groupSeperator = currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator;
        NSString *decimalSeperator = currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator;

        // strip all the format symbols to leave an integer representation
        NSString* newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        newText = [newText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currencySymbol withString:@""];
        newText = [newText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:groupSeperator withString:@""];
        newText = [newText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:decimalSeperator withString:@""];

        NSDecimalNumber *newValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:newText];

        if ([newText length] == 0 || newValue == 0)
            textField.text = nil;
        else if ([newText length] > currencyFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits) {
    //      NSLog(@"We've maxed out the digits");
            textField.text = textField.text;
        } else {
            // update to new value
            NSDecimalNumber *divisor;
            // we'll need a number to divide by if local currency uses fractions
            switch (currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits) {
                // the max fraction digits tells us the number of decimal places
                // divide accordingly based on the 3 available options
                case 0:
    //              NSLog(@"No Decimals");
                    divisor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.0"];
                    break;
                case 2:
    //              NSLog(@"2 Decimals");
                    divisor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100.0"];
                    break;
                case 3:
    //              NSLog(@"3 Decimals");
                    divisor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1000.0"];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            NSDecimalNumber *newAmount = [newValue decimalNumberByDividingBy:divisor];
            textField.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:newAmount];
        }
        return NO;
    }
```