# Formatting a dollar amount in real time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mobile

I am working on an iOS app that requires the user to enter a dollar amount. It needs to allow them to enter dollars and cents with a max value of $9999.99

I want it to work like this:
there is a textfield that displays: "$0.00"
to type $5.25 the input will change with each key press. 
so it would look like this:
'5' is pressed, display: $0.05
'2' is pressed, display: $0.52
'5' is pressed, display: $5.25

I have tried to make this work a number of different ways but all present the problem. 
Using NSNumberformatter does not work correctly. Using a link list or array will not work if the user presses backspace, and I really do not want to implement a stack as I fear it will be too time consuming. Please advise on how I should approach this problem. Thanks

Comment: I think you'd just format the string brute force and display it, updating after each button push.

Comment: can you explain this more?

Comment: NSNumberFormatter would work fine for this (this is a common thing in many apps). Perhaps post how you tried to use it, and someone can point out the mistake.

Comment: Does this help? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388448/re-apply-currency-formatting-to-a-uitextfield-on-a-change-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an indicative example that shows how to do it. You should study this code and readapt it to your situation. Try it:

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    // Here I create the formatter and I set the format. You do this faster with setFormat: .
    NSNumberFormatter* formatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    formatter.maximumIntegerDigits=6;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits=2;
    formatter.currencySymbol= @"$";
    formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator= @".";
    formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator= @",";
    formatter.positivePrefix=@"";

    NSArray* numbers= @[ @1 ,@2 ,@3 ,@4, @5, @6, @7, @8  ];
    // These are the inserted numbers, you should change the code in a way that
    // every number is taken in input from the text field.
    float number=0.0f;
    for(NSUInteger i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        // It just simulates what happens if the user types the numbers in the array.
        number= [numbers[i] floatValue] * 1.0e-2 + number*10;
        NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber: @(number)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tanner is not trying to format a number in dollars and cents. He wants a UITextField that will dynamically format as the user types and deletes characters.

Comment: Is enough to readapt this code to the string taken in input from the text field.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* formattedAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%01d.%02d",dollars,cents];
```